# Example of a diophantine polynomial

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

A diophantine set is a subset of a power $\mathbb{Z}^k$ of the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers which can be written as $$\{x \in \mathbb{Z}^k : \exists y \in \mathbb{Z}^m : P(x, y)=0\}$$ where $P$ is a diophantine polynomial, that is a polynomial in several variables - here, the variables $x$ and $y$ - with integer coefficients.

$$$$

Could you give me an example of such an polynomial?? How can it be that $x \in \mathbb{Z}^k$ and $y \in \mathbb{Z}^m$ ?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

Could you explain to me the following sentence??

> It is evident that a diophantine set is the projection, in the above
>   notation onto the $x$ hyperplane, of the solution set of a diophantine
>   polynomial.

Comment: I have not encountered the phrase "diophantine polynomial" before.  Can you define it or give a reference?

Comment: A diophantine polynomial is a polynomial in several variables with integer coefficients. @lulu

Comment: Do you need example of polynom with integer coefficients? Really?

Comment: But, then what's the problem?  $P(x_1,x_2,y_1) = x_1^2+ x_2 ^2+ y_1^2 +10$ or anything else you could write down, really.

Comment: No... I want to understand how it can be that $x \in \mathbb{Z}^k$ and $y \in \mathbb{Z}^m$... How can i be that they have different number of coordinates? @MichaelGaluza

Comment: I'm at the same place as the other commenter (Michael Galuza)...it seems that you are just asking for a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: @Mary Star Ok, well...is my example good enough?  That one has two x variable and one y.

Comment: Yes... I was confused... Now it is clear.. Thanks!! @lulu

Comment: @MaryStar, let we have polynom with three variables $x$, $y$, $z$. It you want, you can rewrite this polynom as polynom of $x$, and $y, z$ are coeff. Or, $(y,z)\in\mathbb Z^2$

Comment: I guess Diophantine equation should be a equation with integer coordinates, *and* integer solutions. @MaryStar Though I don't understand $\Z^{k}$ thingy, did you mean $\Z_{k}$, numbers modulo k and m , respectively?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}^k$ is a $k$-tuple of $\mathbb{Z}$. @sarker306

Comment: I edited my question above... Could someone of you explain to me the sentence I added?

Comment: @lulu Do you know what the sentence I added in the question above means?

Comment: @Mary Star.  Yes.  "look at all the set of integer solutions to $P(\vec {x},\vec {y})$.  For each such integer solution, discard the y's and keep the x's.  The set of x's you have at the end is the set in question."

Comment: So, a diophantine set is the set of $x$'s. But why is it a projection onto the $x$ hyperplane? Because it contains only the $x$'s and not the $y$'s? @lulu

Comment: Yes.  A projection from from one coordinate space to a subspace just disregards a specified list of coordinates.  In this case, we disregard all the y's (after establishing that they exist).

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-) @lulu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose k = 2, m = 3. So, $x = (x1, x2), y = (y1, y2, y3)$, now consider this equation, $P(x,y) : (3,4).x + (-9,1,0).y = 0$. Here, dot stands for inner vector product. If $x1, x2, y1, y2, y3$ are all integers for some $x$, we can say $x$ is an element of the Diophantine Set defined for $P(x,y)$

> the projection, in the above notation onto the x hyperplane, of the solution set of a diophantine polynomial.

Now, projecting the x would require a 2D plane, as k = 2. We can find infinitely many **x** vectors for the given **P(x, y)** , which can be plotted at this 2D plane. Please note that projecting on x hyperplane doesn't require reduction of dimensionality, and we are only plotting **x** tuples. Why? Because, your definition means, we will only add those **x** tuples, for which there is some **y** tuples *so that* **P(x,y)** = 0.

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-)